# JQUERY-UI Draggables - Seralize is running before the Draggable is complete

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable

I'm using the JQUERY-UI draggable plugin. As a setting, when the Draggable is done, using the STOP setting I run a function to serialize a list of LIs to get their order in terms of their IDs.

For example, if I have an UL, with a list of LIs with the following IDs: 1,2,3,4,5

If I then move 5, between 2&3, the seralize is returning:
1,2,5,3,4,5

Which makes me think that the jQuery UI-Draggable STOP is running before the page is finished rendering, or the DOM isn't update?

Any ideas on how I can fix this from happening. Is there something I can do in my Serialize function to say, wait till jQuery animations are all done, or stop all that are going on to ensure the DOM is accurate?

Answer (score 1):

Try the update event instead of the stop event...

> This event is triggered when the user
>   stopped sorting and the DOM position
>   has changed.

Comment: I assumed you were using the Sortable plugin... it's the one with the update event (and the one I'd use if I were doing reordering within lists)